# Intel RSTe RAID drives appear in BIOS but not in Windows

Tags: windows-10, drivers, raid

I have a HP Z620 workstation running Windows 10.

I moved 4 HDDs into it from an older HP Z420 - these form a RAID volume that was working fine with Intel's RSTe on the old machine.

On the new machine they're plugged into the "SCU" SATA connectors. They appear fine in the SCU BIOS ROM thing:

[image]

But in Windows there's no sign of them at all:

[image]

I don't know what the problem is. The BIOS is setup in RAID+ACHI mode, but only the SSD (my boot drive, not a member of the RAID) appears in the regular HP BIOS:

[image]
[image]

I suspect I don't have some driver loaded that presents the SCH interface to Windows. I installed the Intel RSTe driver for the Z620 (HP's "sp98397.exe"), but it doesn't seem to help.

Suggestions, please!

Comment: What does the Intel RST user interface says?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I can't run the RST user interface. I installed the drivers but haven't figured out how to install the UI.

Comment: So that's probably part of the problem. Try installing the most up-to-date drivers directly from Intel, not the old version from the manufacturer. As usual, ytou should be able to just install it on top of the other. Then check with the user interface.

Comment: I got it working. I installed IATA_CD.exe from the old HP Z420 machine. That's the GUI. Once that was installed the RAID volume showed up in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I installed IATA_CD.exe from the old HP Z420 machine. That's the GUI. Once that was installed the RAID volume showed up in Windows.